# Fill Square with Given Set of Rectangles

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I have a real life problem where I feel like I need some maths or programming help to find the most logical solution.

I have a number of plates, all rectangle with pre-defined different sizes (width length), and I want to make a square tiling with them. There square size is not pre-defined, but I need to use as many of the rectangles as possible (to not to waste them)

There can be certain amount of gaps between these objects, I can fill them with a filling, but once the gap is too much it becomes too obvious. I feel like this is an important detail in the whole problem because things do not have to be "too precise" if that makes any sense.

Not sure where else I can ask this question, and hoping for an existing method to solve this, so I can learn something from this :)

Comment: So, you are assuming that using more rectangles will result in larger gaps and you want to balance the two measures somehow, right? I would probably start with a rectangle packing like [this one](https://github.com/juj/RectangleBinPack). Then, remove the biggest rectangle and try again until you reach a local minimum of your quality measure.

Comment: Are rectangles sizes predefined?

Comment: If you could show some image it would help to understand better your question.

Comment: This kind of a problem is called an "optimal packing problem" and it is an example of a larger topic called "combinatorial optimization". A web search for those terms should turn up lots of hits.

Comment: @NuPagadi yes they are predefined